# How can I fix an PowerPoint VSTO that needs to Read from MS Project and the Version of MS Project Installed is different than the rest of Office?

Tags: powerpoint, vsto, ms-project, ms-project-server-2013, netoffice

I develop a commercially sold PowerPoint VSTO add-in that reads data from open Microsoft Project files. It takes what the user has currently selected in MS Project and creates a PowerPoint chart of it. The PowerPoint Add-in references the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject` library to connect with MS Project.

I have a user who has MS Office 365 installed for the "normal" office suite (Excel, PowerPoint, Word, Outlook) but uses MS Project 2013. Because of this, the PowerPoint add-in is not able to read data from the user's Active MS Project file.

The Add-in works fine when the versions of MS Project and the rest of Office are the same, but seems to lose its interoperability when the installed version of MS Project is lower than the installed version of PowerPoint.

Is there a solution to be able to get these mixed versions of Office to communicate with each other? looking for something other than telling the user "You need to upgrade MS Project to be on the same version as the rest of Office"

Perhaps using a NuGet Package such as [NetOffice](https://netoffice.io/) would resolve this?

Comment: Kenny, This is really a question for the company that created the add-in, I suggest you contact them.

Comment: @john-project I create the add-in

Comment: @KennyArnold can you update your post with additional information? What was the Office version used to develop the PowerPoint Add-in (VSTO works best if the add-in is developed on the same/older version to the Microsoft apps on the client computer)? Is the add-in version 32-bit or 64-bit? Does the client computer have 64-bit Project or is it 32-bit dealing with a 64-bit Office 365 installation? Have you debugged in a dev environment with the same Office/Project versions/bitness as the client? Have you spun up VS 2013/Office 2013 for a lowest common denominator build? What else have you tried?

Comment: I would try building the add-in against the *lowest* version of the office applications you want to support. The office apps are mostly upwards compatible, but not downwards.

Comment: Kenny, sorry I misinterpreted your opening statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by using the [NetOffice](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetOfficeFw.MSProject/) to replace the Microsoft Project Interop dependencies. Super easy switch!